# If-Condition: Why turning a boolean into an integer?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I saw a condition like this:

```
if ((int)method_exists($this, $this->endpoint) > 0)
```

What's behind this? What's the advantage over the obvious

```
if (method_exists($this, $this->endpoint))
```

?

( Source: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/ )

Comment: I can't see any advantage, the first one is slower than the second

Comment: You can force the type return (casting the type) for some reasons, for instance if you want to be sure that the comparison is evaluated with the same type for both the elements... but besides that I think that in this case the code has no big improvement and is even less readable... I would go for the second version.

Comment: is even totally useless, because when you put it to integer you'll have either 1, if method_exists return true or 0, if it returns false and then you test if it's greater than 0 that means different to false, that means equals to true, than return automatically to putting method_exists it self.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any advantage of turning it into an integer. because method_exists already return a boolean. It is a long and useless way of coding.

if statement require a boolean, and method_exists return a boolean, the process added there has the exact same result than using directly method_exists (but waste time and cpu, so please don't do that :D)

Comment: these were my thoughts too (besides not beeing sure about the increased use of ressources). still i wonder, what could have been the motive - since its written by a pro, and for sure there is SOME reason behind it. maybe just a question of taste resp. a habit from another language? well, i just wrote him personally now to ask ;) thanks

Comment: It may be an habit from another language. It actually increases the use of resources(not a lot but using one spoon and half of sugar instead of one is a increased use of resource, even if it's small), because he asks the cpu to do two more operations (conversion to integer, test) before the of the if statement. Ask him and please give his answer here it may help us all. Thanks